# How do I create a generic std::vector destructor?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, destructor

Having a vector containing pointers to objects then using the clear function doesn't call the destructors for the objects in the vector. I made a function to do this manually but I don't know how to make this a generic function for any kind of objects that might be in the vector.

```
void buttonVectorCleanup(vector<Button *> dVector){
    Button* tmpClass;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)dVector.size(); i++){
        tmpClass = dVector[i];

        delete tmpClass;
    }
}
```

This is the function I have that works fine for a specific type of object in the vector but I'd like a single function that could take any kind of vector with object pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing to do is use smart pointers, such as from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).  Then the objects will be deleted automatically.

Or you can make a template function

```
template <class T>
void vectorCleanup(vector<T *>& dVector){
    T* tmpClass;
    for(vector<T*>::size_type i = 0; i < dVector.size(); i++){
        tmpClass = dVector[i];

        delete tmpClass;
    }
```

}

Comment: What I wanted; though it took me a bit of extra work to get it all working though; see: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=250284

Comment: This is the WRONG way to do it. Its not exception safe. You have to explicitly call this to make sure the vector is correctly cleaned up.

Comment: Couple of other things. Pass by reference (you are making a copy of the vector). The vector is still full of pointers (now all invalid). size() does not return 'unsigned'

Comment: You are right abut passing a reference.  size() returns an unsigned integral type, which is probably usigned, but I changed it to correctly use size_type.  I was trying to get rid of the unnecessary cast in the original.

Comment: Keith: • Why don't you pass a `const` reference? • Why do you use explicit indices instead of iterators? • Why the (completely useless and confusing) temporary variable `tmpClass`? • Why is the container type not a type argument (i.e. why support only `vector`s)?

Comment: If I was doing it for myself, I wouldn't use this approach at all, I would use either smart pointers, or one of the boost pointer containers.  In this example, I was trying to keep it as close to the poster's original code as possible.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to use boost's [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). They are highly efficient and safe.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other points - you probably want to pass a reference to the vector, not a copy. tmpClass is not needed - you can delete the pointer directly. You should either resize the vector to 0 or replace the pointers with NULL after deleting - otherwise you could access unallocated memory in the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

I use a special functor to delete the pointer and set it to NULL:

```
struct delete_ptr
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& p)
    {
        delete p;
        p = 0;
    }
};
```

Which is used with `std::for_each` (also don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`):

```
int wmain(int, wchar_t*[])
{
    std::vector<int*> items;
    items.push_back(new int(1));
    items.push_back(new int(2));
    items.push_back(new int(3));
    std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), delete_ptr());
};
```

Comment: You might want to name this delete_and_zero. The zeroing is rather useless if you're going to clear() the vector<T*> anyway.